# SQL Select distinct combinations of columns and sum

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I need to select all distinct combinations of 2 columns: region and make, as well as select a sum for each of these combinations for the total column.

Lets say I have 4 columns

```
ID   Region   Make   total
1      E      blue     2
2      E      red      1
3      E      blue     1
4      W      green    2
5      W      blue     2
6      W      red      1
7      W      red      2
```

now I want a SUM(total) for all unique combinations of region and make.

So my results should look something like this:

```
Region     Make     SUM
  E        blue      3
  E        red       1
  W        green     2
  W        blue      2
  W        red       3
```

i just need a simple select statement like:

```
select distinct........... , SUM(total)
from table1
```

Comment: What have you tired so far ?

Comment: I don't want to say it is not complicated because not everyone have the same SQL knowledge but I want to see if you actually tried something here. Like... do you have a query you tried to make that is not working and you want us to take a look at.. type of query you builded after ready about distinct or SUM.. Overall, I this just looked like a code this for me question.

Comment: i got it now thanks. the query is actually a lot more complicated, i just wanted to see if anyone could do this so i could tweak it to what i need. but i realized i was only including one of the columns in the group by statement. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `group by`to calculate sum based on distinct combinations of columns you specified after the group by class

```
Select Region,Make,SUM(total) as total from table1 group by Region,Make
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select Region, Make, sum(total)
from table1
group by Region, Make
```

Comment: And how it is different from the other two answers?

Comment: @RahulTripathi - On relatively short and easy answers like these, sometimes more than one person writes the same answer at the same time.  As soon as I posted this answer, I saw the others appear, too.  It happens.

Comment: :- I got that point. And I have already given +1 to all the answers. Initially I got that wrong as I thought instead of giving same answers we can upvote it

Answer (score 3):

```
Select Region, Make, Sum(total)
From TableName
Group By Region, Make
```

Comment: I think it would be a better idea to upvote the answers instead of posting similar answers!

Comment: @Rahul: I understand neither your problem nor your tone. All answers have been posted virtually at the same time.

Comment: @Fabian:- The difference between your answer and Haji's answer is just 2 seconds that is acceptable. And I am not saying anything to criticize. I just made a point that it would a better idea to upvote an answer then to post similar answers.P.S. No negative thoughts!

Comment: @Rahul: No offence taken ;) I just think that everyone started to type their answer when there had been none yet, and probably did not reload things in time.

Answer (score 2):

You can aggregate as follows:

```
select region, make, sum(total)
from table1
group by region, make
```